# How to make a react component dependent on production environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, package.json

In my react project created using create-react-app (CRA), I have a CheatPanel component as child of  my App component, structure is:

+-- index
|   +-- App
|   |   +-- CheatPanel

I want this CheatPanel component to only compile/show when I'm building in development environment, and not in production build.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you conditionally render it only when `NODE_ENV !== 'production'`, it won't show in production. For actually not including it in the prod bundle, I think you just need another branch for that.

Comment: Are you using docker for your build?

Comment: No, I'm using react-scripts provided by CRA @MartinWangen-Eriksen